# Managing any HTTP request in a generic way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my organisation, when I want to expose an API, I have to declare it with a swagger contract, same for any update, and it can take multiple weeks before the creation or change is taken into account.

That's why we've come with the idea to declare only one contract for all the APIs we need to expose, and manage the routing in an applicative reverse proxy (the request would include the necessary metadata to allow to route to the appropriate endpoint) :

```
{
  "genericHttpRequest" : base64encodedByteArrayOfAnyHttpRequest
}
```

Now the question is : 
how to manage this request without reimplementing HTTP ? Is it possible to put back the array of byte into a structured HttpServletRequest ?

```
/**
 * Manage a generic request
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/genericRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void manageGenericRequest(@RequestBody GenericHttpRequestDto body) {

  byte[] genericHttpRequest = body.getGenericHttpRequest();

  //(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring will inject a `HttpServletRequest` if it is set as a method parameter. Furthermore, wildcard path mappings will enable the methods to be matched to every request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/generic-endpoint/**")
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> genericGetRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(httpServletRequest.getMethod());
    }
}
```

Optionally, you could return a [`ResponseEntity`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity) to gain more control over your HTTP response.

Comment: Ok, but this is not what my question is about. You have a raw HTTP request in "genericHttpRequest" with headers, any content-type, ... how to put this raw HTTP request back in a structured format ?